# how to implement searchview with Cardview?

Tags: android, searchview, cardview

I've searched for quite a while on a way to implement search functionality with card-view, but that has proven difficult, both due to the lack of guides and my lack of experience in android development.

[Since I haven't got anything major to show from the code side of things, here's the composition of the layout in which I want the search to be conducted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmKMn.png)